# How do you put a comma after the information from selected checkbox into a Textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
       foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)         
       {           
        var chk = row.FindControl("myCheckBox") as CheckBox;
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
        var email = row.FindControl("LabelEmail") as Label;
        txtEmails.Text += (string.Join(",", email.Text));
        }
```

I'm extracting the email from the grid view and suppose to put the email accordingly with a comma separating them. I tried using the string.join method however it's not appearing in the textbox at all. I tried not using string.join but the comma will be added beside every email. How do I separate the email properly?

Example : Helloworld@gmail.com, Helloeveryone@gmail.com, HelloBye@gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
txtEmails.Text += (string.Join(",", email.Text));
```

Try this:

```
txtEmails.Text += email.Text + ", ";
```

Edit:

Because it adds a comma to the the last email, you can do something like this to prevent that:

```
int counter = 0;
// The counter variable must be global
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)         
{           
    var chk = row.FindControl("myCheckBox") as CheckBox;
    if (chk.Checked)
    {
        counter++;
        var email = row.FindControl("LabelEmail") as Label;
        if (counter <= 1)
        txtEmails.Text += email.Text;
        else
        txtEmails.Text += ", " + email.Text;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this method but the comma appear every time after every email even the last one.

Answer (score 2):

string.Join works with the string array, if you pass it a simple string, like in your case, you won't see any change. I think you want to append , after each email address, its better if you use a StringBuilder for your case

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            var chk = row.FindControl("myCheckBox") as CheckBox;
            if (chk.Checked)
            {
            var email = row.FindControl("LabelEmail") as Label;
            sb.Append(email.Text);
            sb.Append(",");
            }
```

In the end you can do:

```
string strEmails = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(','); // TrimEnd to remove the last comma
```

Later you can assign

```
textEmails.Text = strEmails;
```